# Make jQuery or PHP Session data available for other visitors with random (secret) link

Tags: php, jquery, session, random

I need to store data in a session and make it available for other users.

I thought about to store that data in an Session, generate a random Link, which user 1 can send to user 2. The Session should expire after 3 Month.

The session name is the random code I generate which is simluar to the code I send with POST to receive it on the Secretlink with `$_GET`.

Is this working in general or am I on the wrong track?
Can I store a Session even when the user 1 left the website or will the session be terminated?

I also need to set the session via jQuery, but I couldn't find anything about expiration time of a session.

I already did it with a cookie, but of course that's not working with user 2.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are actually files, stored on the server. PHP sets a cookie with the session id, named PHPSESSID. You can also use the PHPSESSID GET parameter, but you would have to change that in the server's PHP settings. Using the GET parameter, you could pass that link to another visitor to let him use the session. You would also have to extend the session expiration time.

However, I wouldn't recommend sharing sessions with GET parameters. It could be a security risk when you are storing personal data in those sessions. I recommend that you write a small script that stores data in a database and that can be accessed (for reading and writing) by requesting an url or any url with a special GET or POST parameter.

One last thing, sessions are never accessible from jQuery directly. You would have to write a small script that requests data on your server via AJAX.